# Why onclick works even if you dont click the button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am creating a simple button via mui but I want to activate the function when I click it but when I enter the web page, it automatically alerts me. I don't know why it is. The function gets called as soon as the page loads without clicking the button.

```
const Rece = () => 

{
    const userId = localStorage.getItem("currentUser");
   

        function submitLiking(name) {
            alert("/"+name+"/" + userId);
          /*  GetWithAuth("/"+name+"/" + userId)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                console.log(result);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error)
            }
        )*/
          }
          const handleEvent = () => {
            alert("I was clicked");
          };

return (

    <div className='listItem-wrap'>
 
        <Button variant="outlined" onClick={submitLiking("favorite")}>Outlined</Button>
        <Button variant="outlined" onClick={submitLiking("remember")}>Outlined</Button>
        <Button variant="outlined">Outlined</Button>


    </div>
)};

export default Rece;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `submitLiking("…")` is evaluated directly. What you should do is define a proper callback:

`onClick={() => submitLiking("favorite")}`

Answer (score -1):

Just try to use event.PreventDefault() or event.stopPropogation() once insde the function
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation